# when and how magento load the options.xml

Tags: layout, javascript

when and how the magento will load the options.xml? But for now, when i login to the admin, there is a javascript error that caused by the magento do not load the colorpicker.js,

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>jquery/jquery.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>jquery/noconflict.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>colorpicker/colorpicker.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>colorpicker/eye.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>colorpicker/utils.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>colorpicker/layout.js?ver=1.0.2</script></action>
            <action method="addCss"><name>colorpicker.css</name></action>
        </reference> 
    </default>
</layout>
```

Comment: Is this a 3rd party extension? Magento, by default does not have jquery. What version of Magento are you on? What is this extension trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot specify css or js files like this:

```
<action method="addJs"><script>colorpicker/layout.js?ver=1.0.2</script></action>
```

This is because Magento looks for the file called `layout.js?ver=1.0.2` and there is no such file on the disk.
You cannot specify versions directly on the xml layout file.
Change the line above to

```
<action method="addJs"><script>colorpicker/layout.js</script></action>
```

or if you want to specify versions for browser cache clearing purposes you can use this extension: https://github.com/jreinke/magento-suffix-static-files